# Using chrome debugger is there a way to see what function called my api?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have like 100 api calls in the network tab for chrome debugger and I want to know what function called for each specific API. 
I can't provide code but I can explain it more
Let say on the Network tab you get like so many different Rest API calls and not all of them are the same and yo want to know for one of them which function called that specific API.

Comment: why don't you add `console.trace()` in every API function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Initiator" column will give you a stack trace of what initiated the network request. For example, here on Stack Overflow:

[image]

As you can see, the request to `validate-body` was made from `send` in jQuery, which came from `ajax`, which came from an anonymous function in Stack Overflow's `post-validation.en.js` script (you can click on the blue underlined text to scroll to each line in question).

Comment: Yes, but that is not really helping because I don't see any function names, i got file names which is still hard to debug

Comment: Like the answer says, you can lick on the blue underlined text, and you'll get to the calling line, which will show the function name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image: Chrome Debugger Network tab]

Comment: Yes, but that is not really helping because I don't see any function names

Comment: What you see here in the popup window is the call stack. If you click on any of the "links", Chome will automatically take you to the function